# Passing tab file paths into QuickImport?

Tags: arcpy, data-interoperability

I'm just trying to add tab file paths into Quickimport to convert to shapefiles. I generate the tab file paths below but just not sure how to load them into Quickimport using for loop?? No python errors reported.

```
import arcpy 
from arcpy import env
import os

path = "C:/temp1"

     for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path,topdown=False):
      for file in files:
         if file.endswith(".TAB"):
             print(os.path.join(root, file))


#Execute Quick Import
  # arcpy.QuickImport_interop("**How do I insert the tab file paths from the above list into here using for loop?**")
```

When its run, there's no errors reported. It prints the list of tab file paths like this..

```
C:/temp\Boundary.TAB 
C:/temp\circle.TAB 
C:/temp\square.TAB 
etc,
```

Answer (score 3):

You're almost there.  Where you have your print statement, just add something like this:

```
table = os.path.join(root, file)
output = #define your output filename or geodatabase here
arcpy.QuickImport_interop(table, output)
```

So, your final loop will look like this:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path,topdown=False):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".TAB"):
            table = os.path.join(root, file)
            print(table)
            output = #define your output filename or geodatabase here
            arcpy.QuickImport_interop(table, output)
```

Here's the [**documentation**](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-interoperability-toolbox/quick-import.htm) on this tool.

Comment: Thanks Fezter, When I included your loop in my code, I received no errors but it converted just one tab file to a shape file(last tab file) and  Quickimport was continually writing to output gdb file through every iteration. I tried taking output= and Quickimport out for the for loop but it still converted just one tab file. How can I get Quickimport to convert all the tab files?